# Regenerating ICU's .dat file for Android

Tags: android, icu

Someone decided that Canada should have 24 hour time by default so I need to modify our ICU data. On Android 5.1 I was able to do a "make" in `icu4c/source/data` and plop the resulting `icudt53l.dat` onto the device in `/system/usr/icu.`

On Android 8.1, I tried the same, but the device would not boot.

```
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313): System zygote died with exception 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.lang.UCharacter.getUnicodeVersion(UCharacter.java:3877) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.text.StringPrep.<init>(StringPrep.java:277) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.text.StringPrep.getInstance(StringPrep.java:314) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.impl.IDNA2003.<clinit>(IDNA2003.java:37) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadClasses(ZygoteInit.java:300) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:128) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313): Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: could not locate data 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.impl.ICUData.getStream(ICUData.java:145) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.impl.ICUBinary.getData(ICUBinary.java:499) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.impl.ICUBinary.getRequiredData(ICUBinary.java:453) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.impl.UCharacterProperty.<init>(UCharacterProperty.java:1221) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  at android.icu.impl.UCharacterProperty.<clinit>(UCharacterProperty.java:1437) 
 09-27 15:12:14.667 E/Zygote  ( 8313):  ... 9 more
```

I made no actual changes to any data files. The resulting `icudt58l.dat` is ~3k less than the committed version of the same file which doesn't seem right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue wth my Android 8.1 source. In my case, because in the icudt58l.dat has no ubidi.icu file, MissingResourceException is thrown.

In the Makefile, ubidi.icu is included by UNI_CORE_DATA and only is built ifneq ($(INCLUDE_UNI_CORE_DATA),).

That is, you have to include INCLUDE_UNI_CORE_DATA in the make command.

```
make INCLUDE_UNI_CORE_DATA=1
```

And Here is all the commands that I use:

```
cd external/icu/icu4c

mkdir build

cd build

../source/runConfigureICU Linux --with-data-packaging=archive

# work around if there is no xlocale.h file in your environment
sudo ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

make INCLUDE_UNI_CORE_DATA=1

adb root; adb remount; adb push ./data/out/icudt58l.dat system/usr/icu/icudt58l.dat

adb shell stop; adb shell start
```